# Calculate total on checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

**HTML**

```
<div id="catlist">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_1" value="cat_1" price="1.5" /><label for="cat_1">cat_1</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_2" value="cat_2" price="2" /><label for="cat_2">cat_2</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_3" value="cat_3" price="3.5" /><label for="cat_3">cat_3</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_4" value="cat_4" price="4" /><label for="cat_4">cat_4</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_5" value="cat_5" price="5" /><label for="cat_5">cat_5</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_6" value="cat_6" price="6.5" /><label for="cat_6">cat_6</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_7" value="cat_7" price="7" /><label for="cat_7">cat_7</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_8" value="cat_8" price="8" /><label for="cat_8">cat_8</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_9" value="cat_9" price="9.5" /><label for="cat_9">cat_9</label>
</div>
<input type="text" id="total" value="0"  />
```

**Javascript**

```
function calcAndShowTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    $('#catlist :checkbox[checked]').each(function(){
        total =+ parseFloat($(this).attr('price')) || 0;
    });
    $('#total').val(total);
}

$('#pricelist :checkbox').click(function(){
    calcAndShowTotal();
});

calcAndShowTotal();
```

I am getting particular value. WHY? I tried sum of total, i tried jquery but no success..

Comment: where is `#pricelist` ?

Comment: Instead of `=+` it should be `+=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `$('#catlist :checkbox:checked')` selector to select `checked` check-boxes
- `[]` is used as `attribute selector` and it could be used as `'[type="checkbox"]'` but it will not filter `checked` check-boxes
- `+` operator is not needed before `parseFloat`, it has to be `total =+`
- Instead of calling handler, just invoke change handler using `.change()`

```js
function calcAndShowTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $('#catlist :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).attr('price')) || 0;
  });
  $('#total').val(total);
}

$('#catlist :checkbox').change(calcAndShowTotal).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="catlist">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_1" value="cat_1" price="1.5" />
  <label for="cat_1">cat_1</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_2" value="cat_2" price="2" />
  <label for="cat_2">cat_2</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_3" value="cat_3" price="3.5" />
  <label for="cat_3">cat_3</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_4" value="cat_4" price="4" />
  <label for="cat_4">cat_4</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_5" value="cat_5" price="5" />
  <label for="cat_5">cat_5</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_6" value="cat_6" price="6.5" />
  <label for="cat_6">cat_6</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_7" value="cat_7" price="7" />
  <label for="cat_7">cat_7</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_8" value="cat_8" price="8" />
  <label for="cat_8">cat_8</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_9" value="cat_9" price="9.5" />
  <label for="cat_9">cat_9</label>
</div>
<input type="text" id="total" value="0" />
```

**Using `Array#reduce`**

```js
function calcAndShowTotal() {
  var total = [].reduce.call($('#catlist :checkbox:checked'), function(a, b) {
    return a + +$(b).attr('price') || 0;
  }, 0);
  $('#total').val(total);
}

$('#catlist :checkbox').change(calcAndShowTotal).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="catlist">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_1" value="cat_1" price="1.5" />
  <label for="cat_1">cat_1</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_2" value="cat_2" price="2" />
  <label for="cat_2">cat_2</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_3" value="cat_3" price="3.5" />
  <label for="cat_3">cat_3</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_4" value="cat_4" price="4" />
  <label for="cat_4">cat_4</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_5" value="cat_5" price="5" />
  <label for="cat_5">cat_5</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_6" value="cat_6" price="6.5" />
  <label for="cat_6">cat_6</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_7" value="cat_7" price="7" />
  <label for="cat_7">cat_7</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_8" value="cat_8" price="8" />
  <label for="cat_8">cat_8</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_9" value="cat_9" price="9.5" />
  <label for="cat_9">cat_9</label>
</div>
<input type="text" id="total" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping you can use [**change**](https://api.jquery.com/change/) which will respond to and change event on the checkbox. Also you need add or subtract value like this `+=` for addition on `-=` for subtraction

```
var _total = 0;
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
  _total += parseFloat($(this).attr('price')) || 0;
  }
else{
  _total -= parseFloat($(this).attr('price')) || 0;
}
$('#total').val(_total);
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/oa4zxLvb/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
var totalprice=0;
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
totalprice+= parseFloat($(this).attr('price'));
});
$('#total').val(totalprice)
});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".